# How can I get react-i18next to work with storybook?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, storybook

I have react-i18next working for the code that runs in the browser, however all our storybook examples are broken because we only test an individual component.

Can someone explain (with examples) how to get storybook that shows individual components working with react-i18next?

Comment: If you say that they are broken, may I ask how that looks like? Do they just not show up? Do you get error messages? Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Just added a storybook example to react-i18next examples: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/storybook

did not run into any issue...could you please give us more detail on your configuration?

Comment: You are using your own service as a backend. Could you please create an example of storybook with an XHR backend? Everything works with the XHR backend in the app code. But in the storybook it tries to fetch the locale files from the `/public` folder but storybook created with create-react-app doesn't serve it so they are always missing.

Comment: just check storybook documentation: https://storybook.js.org/configurations/serving-static-files/#2-via-a-directory